# Filter part of the html page when scraping results with Scrapy

Tags: html, python-3.x, filter, scrapy

I want to scrape the products that are listed in [this webpage](https://www.sephora.fr/marques/de-a-a-z/burberry-burb/). So I tried to extract all of the `data-tcproduct` attributes from the `div.product-tile`. It contains numerous things including the url of the products I need to visit.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

So I did:

```
def parse_brand(self, response):
    for d in set(response.css('div.product-tile::attr(data-tcproduct)').extract()):
        d = json.loads(d)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=d['product_url_page'].replace("p","P"), callback=self.parse_item)
```

Yet, I noticed that some attributes from the `div.product-tile` seems to be hidden in the page and I am not interested by them. Those I want to scrape are rather on `product-listing-title`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

So how can I filter part of the HTML page when scraping results with Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need `product-listing-title`. You need items from `search-result-content` `div` instead:

```
for d in response.css('div.search-result-content div.product-tile::attr(data-tcproduct)').extract():
        d = json.loads(d)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=d['product_url_page'].replace("p","P"), callback=self.parse_item)
```